# Creating a field with the same value as an existing, nested field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've seen a lot of docs and questions on how to create a field with an existing field's value, but none that I've read explain how to create a field with an existing but **nested** value.

Here's are two examples of the queries I've tried to run:

```
db.getCollection('bots').find({name:/PORTER/}).update({ $set: {'theme.css.greeterFontColor' : $theme.css.primaryColor}})
```

```
db.getCollection('bots').find({name:/PORTER/}).update({ $set: {'theme.css.greeterFontColor' : '$theme.css.primaryColor'}})
```

In both cases, a new field hasn't been created.

**edit** - I disagree that this is a duplicate because that linked question only covers values that aren't nested, and the solutions offered in the answers haven't worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: see my edit on why i disagree this is a dupe